# Isotropically conjugate points in reductive spaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, homogeneous-spaces

Is it the case that a naturally reductive Riemannian homogeneous space that contains a pair of conjugate points necessarily contains a pair of isotropically conjugate points? That is, there is a pair of conjugate points whose Jacobi field is the restriction of a Killing field?